# Подходит ли MacBook с el Capitan для программирования?

Tags: macbook

Хочу заменить свой старый ноутбук с windows 10 на MacBook.
Характеристики:

Процессор  Intel Core i5, оперативная память 4 Гб Ddr3, видеокарта  встроенная Intel hd graphics 5000, видеопамять 1536 мб.
Операционная система IS X El Capitan с возможностью смены на более новую.

Подойдет ли данный ноутбук для программирования на python, c# и c++?
И потянет ли он python 3.11 и python 3.12 3.13 когда они выйдут? Поддерживает ли это ноутбук visual studio 2022 и visual studio code?

Comment: Извините, т9 исправил Intel core i5 на it и OS X El Capitan на Is

Comment: Я не знаю, какой должен быть комп, чтобы он не потянул обычный интерпретатор python...

Comment: @Али-МухаммадЗакарьяев Опечатки в вопросе можно исправить. Для этого есть кнопка "Править" под вопросом

Comment: И еще интересно, какая именно IS X El Capitan используется?

Comment: 10.11.6 вот эта

Comment: Ну, значит точно подойдет.

Comment: спасибо вам !!!!

Comment: visual studio 2022 требует системы версии не ниже 11, так что не пойдет. visual studio code может заработать, однако с 4 Гб памяти будет не разгуляться. С такими характеристиками возможна разработка только в простом текстовом редакторе и командной строке. "старый ноутбук с windows 10" - ¿а у него какие характеристики? неужели еще хуже, чем у этого макбука?

Comment: не поверите у него(у старого) core i3, 3 гб оперативной памяти, и видеокарта geforce 320m. так он тянул unity, visual studio, vs code и davinci resolve. но на этот макбук я могу установить обновления

Answer (score -1, accepted):

MacBook поддерживает visual studio 2022 и visual studio code. C# и C++ входят в его состав, так что можешь не беспокоиться. Python должен потянуть, если версия macOs не древнее десятой.

Еще, конечно, дело зависит от того, что собираешься программировать, может не хватить оперативной памяти.

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: а можно ли поменять операционку на более новую?

Comment: Сам говорил, что можешь...

Comment: Ой то есть поставить самую последнюю версию